# How to remove empty spaces in JS var?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

How can I remove empty space in the **var con_str** after I join the push value?

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chckBox1" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref"> Banana </a>
<input type="checkbox" id="chckBox2" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref"> Apple </a>
<input type="checkbox" id="chckBox3" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref"> Orange </a>

<input type="button" id="testABC" onclick="submit()" value="OK" />
```

JS

```
function fnTest(check) 
{
    $(check).is(':checked')
}

function submit() 
{
    var values = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        values.push($(this).next("").text());
    });

    var con_str = "https://www.url-abc.com/"+values.join();
    window.open(con_str.trim());
}
```

This is the output that I've right now if I select all three checkboxes.

```
https://www.url-abc.com/%20Banana%20,%20Apple%20,%20Orange
```

The output that I wanted

```
https://www.url-abc.com/Banana,Apple,Orange
```

I tried added con_str.**trim()**. But it didn't work.

Here's the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/izzatz/yx7bn59r/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<a>`s' contents have spaces on the ends. Trim them.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    values.push($(this).next("").text().trim());
});
```

A more elegant method, using `.map` instead of `.push`:

```
const values = [...$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")]
  .map(input => input.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim());
```

Comment: ahh shoot! That is one silly mistake. I thought trim will handle it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()`, `get()` and `join()` to get a comma separated string like the following way:

```
var values = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function(){
    return $(this).next("").text().trim();
}).get().join(',');
```

**Demo:**

```js
function fnTest(check) 
{
    $(check).is(':checked')
}

function submit() 
{
    var values = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).next("").text().trim();
    }).get().join(',');

    var con_str = "https://www.url-abc.com/"+values;
    console.log(con_str)
    //window.open(con_str.trim());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chckBox1" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref"> Banana </a>
<input type="checkbox" id="chckBox2" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref"> Apple </a>
<input type="checkbox" id="chckBox3" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref"> Orange </a>

<input type="button" id="testABC" onclick="submit()" value="OK" />
```